# Tortoise SVN hangs after being idle

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

All Tortoise SVN operations hang on the first try after being idle. I don't have a specific time for how long it's idle before this starts happening. If I cancel the operation and do it again, it instantly works the way it should.  A couple example of where this is happening are,

- Check Log
- Check for Modifications
- Commit

Comment: Please describe your environment: TortoiseSVN version, SVN server version, configuration...

Comment: Windows Tortoise SVN: v1.9.5, Server is Subversion Edge 5.2.x. Both are on the same network.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you solved it on your side ?

Comment: Still having the same problem